# Gremlin remote command fails with timeout error: Host did not respond in a timely fashion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin

I connected to a remote gremlin server via gremlin groovy shell. Connection succeeded. But for any remote command I try to execute it gives timeout error. Even for command `:> 1+1`

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/senthil.yaml
==>Connected - 10.40.40.65/10.40.40.65:50080

gremlin> :> 1+1
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
Display stack trace? [yN]
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:101)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

This is my conf file: remote.yaml

```
hosts: [10.40.40.65]
port: 50080
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

I'm using dynamodb + titan.

Answer (score 4):

You might not have a truly successful connection. The console (and underlying driver) is optimistic in that it really doesn't fail a connection until a request is sent as it expects the server may come online "later".  I would go back to investigating if the server is running, if you have the right IP, if the `host` property is not set to something like "localhost" if you are connecting remotely, if the port is open, that you are using a compatible version of TinkerPop, etc.

Comment: Adding to Stephen's response, make sure the `host` and `port` values match in the Gremlin Console `remote.yaml` and in the Gremlin Server `gremlin-server.yaml`. It looks like you've modified them in `remote.yaml` from the default values.