# Gremlin remote command fails on azure cosmosDB: Host did not respond in a timely fashion

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I was following the guide [create-graph-gremlin-console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-gremlin-console) for setting up the **gremlin console** with **CosmosDB**.

My remote-secure.yaml file is:

```
hosts: [***.documents.azure.com]
port: 433
username: /dbs/graphdb/colls/person
password: <PRIMARY KEY>
connectionPool: {enableSsl: false}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

and when I ran the command `:> g.V().count()`, I get

> Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and
>   submit again.

You can see my terminal for the stack trace.

[image: asciicast]

---

- I'm using **gremlin console 3.3.0**
- I already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832957/gremlin-remote-command-fails-with-timeout-error-host-did-not-respond-in-a-timel), but didn't found the answer very useful.
- I checked the status of my CosmosDB server, & it is working fine
- I used same configuration in `Node.js` app and it works fine there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Host needs to be ****.graphs.azure.com, instead of ***.documents.azure.com.
2. Port needs to be 443.